GPU doesn't load if my monitor is turned off and pc is turned on by WOL
So i'm bit with a little problem:

PC for AI server, sometimes i need to turn on the pc by wol and the monitor is turned off. The pc turns on fine and the OS loads but after some hours, when i need to access the pc, i turn on the monitor and nothing, like the gpu never loaded, i even sometimes tried to turn off the monitor, turn the pc by wol and if i don't turn on the  monitor after passing the bios loading or GRUB, the graphics won't turn on until i restart the pc again.

Specs of the pc:

AMD Ryzen 5 5500
Motherboard MSI A320M Grenade
OS: Ubuntu Server 22.04
GPU: MSI Nvidia RTX 4060 Ti 16GB

Can someone help me? Is there something on the BIOS I can turn off/on to prevent this... or even something on GRUB or linux?
Expection: Turn on the pc by wol with monitor turned off and after some minutes when i need to use the pc physically (not remotely) i just turn on the monitor and done, no need to reboot the pc.

What type of monitor? / Does changing the monitor affect the behavior? - Not 100% sure it's relevant, just looking for patterns.

Have seen that with PCs using display port. It's like both screen and PC need to be newly on and still looking the other to work. If one is on and fails to see the other, it's like it sleeps and turns off that port. When the other is turned on, there's no signal saying there's anything at the other end of the cable, checking doesn't wake the other end, and then the other device also stops sending/receiving anything on that port.

The monitor should be detectable, whether it's turned off or on. However, without a detected monitor on boot, the GPU driver might not initialize and require a reboot.
Things to try:

Don't turn off the monitor but instead rely on power save. I'm using a script to change the idle timeout to 1 minute (when I'm away) or to 30 minutes (for normal use).
Connect a monitor dummy/simulator to an unused GPU output. That way, the driver should load regardless and be able to detect the monitor once it's been turned on.
With another GPU present (doesn't look like it though), there might be a software/driver switch to force loading the 4060 as primary.


Sorry for the delayed reply. So the first solution you said is not very good for me as i need to have power save disabled. The third one is also not possible as my motherboard only has one slot for the gpu (M-ATX). I may gonna need to buy a monitor dummy... But I would love to have another solution instead of buying more things...
